# Is it possible to perform the Lomcovak manoeuvre in a C152 aerobat?

Tags: aerobatics

Has anyone performed a [Lomcovak manoeuvre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomcovak) in a C152 aerobat, is it even possible, or would that likely overstress the engine?

Comment: Just from reading the article you linked, I'd strongly advise against doing this with a Cessna.

Comment: @jjack: the [152 Aerobat](http://airandspace.si.edu/collections/artifact.cfm?object=nasm_A20070077000) is sturdier than your typical Cessna, rated +6g / -3g. Doesn't mean it could do a Lomcovak, but it might be strong enough. Depends a lot on the engine & engine mount, I imagine.

Comment: The maneuver was originally performed in a Zlin, which could do around +10g, depending on the model. This is a fully aerobatics capable aircraft.

Comment: Yeah, but the Lomcovak is primarily negative g, right? Is the Zlin that did the maneuver +/-10g?

Comment: Supposedly, telling from the wing loading (positive) given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zl%C3%ADn_Z_26

Comment: I noticed I made an error in the load factor computation. The Zlin aerobatic only did +7. The source given gives the load factor for the trainer for steady level flight, not the maximum load factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of approved maneuvers is in the POH, and I'm sure the Lomcovak is not listed. If you are willing to do unapproved maneuvers, the issue is that because the aircraft tumbles rather than flies in this maneuver you have a few things to worry about: it starts with an outside maneuver, it is inverted, and the exit requires a high-speed dive which will exceed Vne or the +6g the 152 Aerobat is rated for.